# How to limit Flutter bloc creation

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc

I have an application which required the writing of many blocs.

Several pages use the same bloc. For example, messaging pages use the MessagingBloc.

Currently, I use a global multi-provider to dispatch blocs to child widgets. The problem is: when I change pages (so I no longer use the messaging feature), the bloc is, logically, still present in the tree structure.

**Do you know a way to have in the tree, only the blocs that are currently in use?** (maybe working with one Navigator by feature but it seems too complicated/expensive)